# Button disabled by default - selenium web driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download csv file from below URL using Selenum webdriver.
[nse bulk deals](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/bulk.htm)

[screenshot nse bulk deals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NERsq.png)

I tried most of the ways to click "Get Data" button and it's clickable. This button is gets disabled only in chrome remote controlled mode but if we open the url in browser it works fine.

Is there a way to fix this problem ?

Comment: nope, theres no way

Comment: @HirasawaYui - the button works fine if we open that URL in browser. It facing an issue when i opened using webdriver.